# firstName.lastName regular expression using regularexpressionvalidator in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, regex, validation

How can I make a regular expression that would say the following:

FirstName.LastName or FirstName.Letter.LastName

To allow example:

- John.Smith
- John.S.Smith

Not to allow example:

- John Smith
- John
- John.
- John.Smi th
- John.S.D.Smith

Thanks in advance!

Greg

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works; I've tested it with all of your examples:

```
^[A-Za-z]+\.([A-Za-z]\.)?[A-Za-z]+$
```

Explanation:

`^` - anchor to match the start of your string
`[A-Za-z]+\.` - match a letter 1 or more times followed by a period
`([A-Za-z]\.)?` - optionally match a single letter followed by a period
`[A-Za-z]+` - match a letter 1 or more times
`$` - anchor to match the end of your string

Hope this helps! For quick reference on regular expressions, see [here](http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/46/CSharp-Regular-Expressions-Cheat-Sheet).

Answer (score 1):

You could use this pattern: `[a-zA-Z]+\.([a-zA-Z]\.)?[a-zA-Z]+`

Bear in mind that this will not enforce capitalization of the names, so "john" or "John" are valid. You could enforce this by placing an additional `[A-Z]` at the beginning of each name portion and making the remainder match on `[a-z]` but that might be a hassle for your users. Instead you could apply this capitalization in the back-end.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this

`\w+\.\w\.\w+|\w+\.\w+`

Which should happily catch your good examples and ignore your bad examples.